# Creates duplicate record

Tags: trigger

```
trigger Opportunity_SFDCWithAccount on Opportunity_SFDC__c (after insert,after update,before update) 
{
   if(Trigger.isafter)
   {
       if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate )
       {
           Set<Id> objSet = new Set<Id>();
           String s1;
           String s2;
           String s3;
           for (Opportunity_SFDC__c opp : Trigger.New)
           {
              system.debug('22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222'+ opp.Id);     
              objSet.add(opp.Id);   
           }
           List<Opportunity_SFDC__c> lstOpp = [Select Id, Account__r.Name, Name FROM Opportunity_SFDC__c WHERE Id IN : objSet]; 
           List<Opportunity_SFDC__c> lstOpp1 = new List<Opportunity_SFDC__c>();
           for(Opportunity_SFDC__c objOpp : lstOpp)
           {   
             if(objOpp.Name.Contains(objOpp.Account__r.Name + ' - ') == false)
             {
              s1 = objOpp.Account__r.Name ;       
              s2 = ' - '; 
              s3 = s1 + s2 + objOpp.Name;
              if(s3.length()>80)
              {
                  objOpp.Name = s3.subString(0,79);
              }
              else
              {
                  objOpp.Name = s3;
              }
              lstOpp1.add(objOpp);
             } 
           }
           if(lstOpp1.size()>0)
           update lstOpp1;  
         }

   } 

  if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isUpdate)
  {
      Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id> ();
      for(Opportunity_SFDC__c opp : Trigger.New){
           if(opp.Opportunity_Owner__c == null ){
              accountIds.add(opp.Account__c);
           }
      }
      Map<Id, Account> AccountOwnerMap = new Map<Id, Account>( [Select id, OwnerId From Account Where id in : accountIds]); 
      for(Opportunity_SFDC__c opp : Trigger.New){
          if(opp.Opportunity_Owner__c == null ){
          if(AccountOwnerMap.get(opp.Account__c) != null)
              opp.Opportunity_Owner__c = AccountOwnerMap.get(opp.Account__c).OwnerId;
          }
      }
  }


  /*Trigger to create a note when Next step is filled 
       if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter)
{
    List<Note> notes = new List<Note>();
    List<Opportunity_SFDC__c> oppList = new List<Opportunity_SFDC__c>();

    for(Opportunity_SFDC__c opp: Trigger.new) 
    {
        if(opp.Next_Update__c != null && opp.Next_Update__c.trim() != '' )
       {
            notes.add(new Note(
              Title = 'Next Update',
              Body = opp.Next_Update__c, 
              ParentId = opp.Id));


          oppList.add(new Opportunity_SFDC__c (id = opp.id, Next_Update__c= null));
      }
   }
     insert notes;
     update oppList;
}

if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isBefore)
{
    List<Note> notes = new List<Note>();

    for(Opportunity_SFDC__c opp: Trigger.new) 
    {
        if(opp.Next_Update__c != null && opp.Next_Update__c.trim() !='' )
       {
            notes.add(new Note(
              Title = 'Next Update',
              Body = opp.Next_Update__c, 
              ParentId = opp.Id));

          opp.Next_Update__c= '';

      }
   }
     insert notes;       
}*/
```

}

Requirement: When a text field on opportunity is filled with a value a note should get created. but my code is creating duplicate notes & this happens only on creation of opportunity. Can anybody please help.

Comment: Guest610 It would really help if you could also explain what your code is doing and what you've already done to debug this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Read [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) carefully and you will see that:

> If the record was updated with workflow field updates, fires before
>   update triggers and after update triggers one more time (and only one
>   more time)

So it is possible that the insert is followed by an update.

One way to avoid the duplicates is to have a class with a static field holding the opportunity ID values in a set that have already had notes inserted; only insert the notes for opportunities not already in the set.

Answer (score 0):

I created another class to avoid duplication of the records. I am attaching my code below.

```
 /* Trigger to create a note when Next step is filled  */


       if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter && checkRecursive.runOnce())
{
    List<Note> notes = new List<Note>();
    List<Opportunity_SFDC__c> oppList = new List<Opportunity_SFDC__c>();


    for(Opportunity_SFDC__c opp: Trigger.new) 
    {
        if(opp.Next_Update__c != null && opp.Next_Update__c != '')
       {
            notes.add(new Note(
              Title = 'Next Update',
              Body = opp.Next_Update__c, 
              ParentId = opp.Id));


          oppList.add(new Opportunity_SFDC__c (id = opp.id, Next_Update__c = ''));
      }
   }
     insert notes;
     update oppList;
}

if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isBefore)
{
    List<Note> notes = new List<Note>();

    for(Opportunity_SFDC__c opp: Trigger.new) 
    {
        if(opp.Next_Update__c != null && opp.Next_Update__c != '')
       {
            notes.add(new Note(
              Title = 'Next Update',
              Body = opp.Next_Update__c, 
              ParentId = opp.Id));

          opp.Next_Update__c= '';

      }
   }
     insert notes;       
}
```

}

Here is the code for the checkRecursive class.

```
    public Class checkRecursive
    {
         private static boolean run = true;
         public static boolean runOnce()
         {
          if(run)
              {
                 run = false;
                 return true;
              }
          else
            {
               return run;
            }
        }
       }
```